# Can't set DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item.Text on C# (Crystal Reports 13)

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I need to set a formula to dinamically change a bitmap path in a Crystal Report. I've been reading this could be achieved creating the formula in the Formula Field in CR and then modifying it through C# like this:

```
MyReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields.Item("FormulaName").Text = "formula";
```

However, when I try to do it like this, the .Item attribute is nowhere to be found. I'm using CR 13 32-bit, already looked on SAP forums and no one knows anything. Do I have to do something else to get this to work??

Comment: Are you using this statement: "using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;"?

Comment: No, the namespace was CrystalDecisions.Shared; . Tried with CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine; but it doesn't show Item either.

Comment: Do you have the reference to CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine in your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
MyReport.DataDefinition.FormulaFields["FormulaName"].Text = "Formula";
```

The method was updated and was nowhere in documentation.

Comment: Good find, make sure to mark it as answer. I'm sure other people will be looking for that soon!

Comment: I'll have to wait for 2 days to do so. Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the reference `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine` to your solution and then add the statement `using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;` to the code on your page.

Comment: The reference to .Engine was already there. I took out the .Shared namespace and put .Engine instead, but it still doesn't works.